# remove row index after using from_dict function with orient="index" option

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe using the below code in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

a = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a,orient="index")
print(df1)
```

The output for the same is:

[image]

I want to remove the 0 which is seen in the first row. But I am unable to do so. I have tried the following:

```
df1.drop(df1.index[0],inplace=True)
```

This gives the following output which is not desired:

[image]

I have also tried which removes the index a,b and c.

```
df1.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
```

I want to further store this data frame to Excel using the below code:

```
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Summary")
```

Here I don't want the extra 0 in the row. I would like to know if there is any way the row with 0 can be removed either in the dataframe or while writing it in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the row. `0` is the name of the column. To prevent the column from exporting to excel you can pass the optional parameter `header=False`

```
df1.to_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name="Summary", header=False)
```